# Can I connect to a database in a php file, and then make queries in an included file without connecting again?

Tags: php, mysql, include, rdbms

I am wondering about the scope of the include files. I tested it and it did not work, I am unsure about my problem is the scope. If I can do this, I will look for problems in other parts.

in the parent file

```
mysql_connect("ip and port","name","password"); 
mysql_select_db("fskea1");
```

In the included file

```
mysql_query("select * from blabla).
```

gave me

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]:  Access denied for user
>   'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   D:\Home\fskea1.com\httpdocs\wquest\register.php on line 20 Warning:
>   mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not
>   be established in D:\Home\fskea1.com\httpdocs\wquest\register.php on
>   line 20

update: I tried adding the connection to the child include file and now it works. Appearantly, I need to connect to database in each php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work - I've done it myself for sub-forms on a web page.

If the included file is imported using `include('xyz.php')` then it will work OK. Not sure whether it will work via `readfile` - never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You probably have a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem. For more information, you'd need to show some code.

Comment: I tried adding the connection to the child include file and now it works. Appearantly, I need to connect to database in each php file.

Comment: @Uğur nope, you definitely don't need to do that. How are you doing the include()? You are including a local file and not a `http://` one, correct?

Answer (score 0):

This has always worked for me:

```
<?php

function openDB() {
    $link = $GLOBALS['link'];
    if (!isset($link)) $link= @mysql_connect( 'host', 'user', 'pw');
    if (!$link) {
        return 0;
    } elseif (!mysql_select_db('database-name', $link)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}

$link = openDB();
```

Then, elsewhere:

```
<?php
if (!$link) $link = openDB();
mysql_query("select * from blabla");
```